# Query to retrieve Long Text works in Sequel Pro but returns empty in PHP/Mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Here's my query: `SELECT text FROM data ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;`

I just want the bottom row, and in Sequel Pro, that query retrieves it.

Here's the `PHP/MySQLi`:

```
$query = "SELECT text FROM data ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;"; 
$q_result = mysqli_query($db_server, $query); 
if ($q_result->connect_errno) { 
     echo "error"; 
} else { 
    $result = mysqli_fetch_array($q_result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    mysqli_free_result($q_result); 
    $text = $result["text"]; 
 }
```

The data I'm trying to retrieve is `TEXT`, not a `VARCHAR` or a `BLOB`, and the `$result` variable is coming back empty. Same query, different responses. 
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you print `$q_result->num_rows` ?

Comment: Did you echo `$text` anywhere to see the value in there

Comment: If its resolved, accept one of the answers that helped you the most. And upvote any others that were useful. Thats how SO works. Dont amend your question with FIXED mesages

Answer (score 1):

Remove that semicolon at the end of query and it will be fine.

```
$query = "SELECT text FROM data ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: Who is upvoting this answer. Being friendly is fine, but **upvoting incorrect answers** is not useful.

Comment: if he removes the semi-colon he will get the results.My answer is correct @RiggsFolly

Comment: Mysql has delimiter semi-colon in it and there is no need to write it in query.

Comment: Correct there is no need to use the semi colon. But it is not a problem if you do. It does not cause an error. **test it**

Answer (score 0):

You would only test `connect_errno` after dong a `mysqli_connect()` here you would check for errors using

```
$query = "SELECT text FROM data ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1"; 
$q_result = mysqli_query($db_server, $query); 

// if the query fails mysqli_query() returns false
if ( ! $q_result) { 
    // show yourself the error message generated by MYSQL
    echo $db_server->error; 
    // and at this ppoint you may as well exit
    exit;
}
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($q_result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$text = $result["text"]; 
// not strictly necessary, as PHP will do that when it terminates
mysqli_free_result($q_result); 

// and of course echo the output
echo $text'
```

Answer (score 0):

[mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) returns true on success and false on failure.

> mysqli_query()
>
> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

```
$query = "SELECT text FROM data ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;";
$q_result = mysqli_query($db_server, $query);
if (!$q_result) {
    echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($db_server);
} else {
    $result = mysqli_fetch_array($q_result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    mysqli_free_result($q_result);
    $text = $result["text"];
    echo $text;
}
```